# ISAPI Rewrite 3 rule syntax

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, isapi

I'm installing ISAPI Rewrite 3. I'd like to do the following with it:

The box serving HTTP documents with ISAPI Rewrite 3 has a hypothetical URL of http://www.foo.com.

I want a rule that will point http://www.foo.com/blog to http://blog.foo.com. I don't want a physical redirection. I prefer a proxy so that it doesn't look like we're ever leaving www.foo.com.

How would one write this rule with ISAPI Rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^blog$ http://blog.example.com/ [P]
```